# SSAS Cube excel pivot table drill down

Tags: sql, excel, pivot, ssas, cube

In excel, when you double click on a number in the pivot table, it creates a new sheet with some drill down information.

My question is how do I control what is being shown in the section? To add or delete.
If someone can point me in the right direction inside cube that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SSAS cube go to the actions tab. There, you can define drillthrough actions and specify what dimensions/measures show up for that action. You can also set them to be the default drill under the advanced portion of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this perticular function you ask of is named "drillthrough", not "drill down"